# Chronograf URL not working in AWS

Tags: telegraf, django-chronograph

I have installed TICK stack on my EC2 instance. But not able to access the same with http://:8888 . Do i need to any other setup to access the Chronograf interface.

Please advise

Comment: I added a custom TCP rule and opened security groups to access port :8888

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a custom TCP rule and opened security groups to access port :8888